# error 404 while using {{url()}} on laravel ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

Greating,
I have some error while using ajax on laravel, the console return 404,
that's my ajax

```
$('#btn_search_postcode').click(function(e){
        let postcode = $('#postcode').val();
        if(postcode != ""){
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "{{route('company.postcode')}}",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data:{
                    'id':postcode
                },
                success: function(result){
                    if(result != ""){
                        console.log(result.prefectureid);
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log('null');
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

I have change the url to "{{url('company/postcode')}}/"+postcode but still error
that's my route

```
Route::GET('/company/postcode/{id}', 'mycontroller\companyController@getPostCode')->name('company.postcode');
```

but the code working fine when I change the url into

```
url: "http://localhost/mylaravel/public/company/postcode/"+postcode,
```

I can't use the last method because in other pc using different port.

can anybody help me for this issue?
note : i can see the csrf token, when i add the csrf token again in ajax, I see 2 token on error link

**EDIT:**
I still not resolve that, but now im using `url:rootUrl+"/companies/postcode/"+postcode,` to resolve that issue, is it ok to do like that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your route has a required parameter `{id}` and since you don't provide it when you render the url of the route, laravel doesn't find the route.
Two solutions:

- make the id parameter optional in your route declaration like so `Route::GET('/company/postcode/{id?}', 'mycontroller\companyController@getPostCode')->name('company.postcode');` (note the `{id?}`)
- provide the parameters trough php with some defined variable in the view ex: `{{route('company.postcode',$id)}}`

Cordially

Comment: I'm use +postcode to the Id, and try use the variable id too. and in the above i write in the data: { id: postcode}, but in my original code I'm using `"{{url('companies/postcode')}}/"+id,` but that have a same error

Comment: That will not work because the route is rendered by using php not js. When you do `{{url('companies/postcode')}}` you first render the route in php and laravel doesn't find it as i exmplained.
If you want to concat you php route with some js id, make you parameter optional as explained`{id?}`

Answer (score 0):

you have to change it like these

```
url: "{{url('company/postcode')}}"+'/'+postcode
```

please try these and let me know what happened

Comment: thank's for your answer, i have trried that's but the result got the same error

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, you have a route that is named company.postcode, is that correct? If you do have that route, and now what you are wanting is to get the company by postcode, you will need to take advantage of Laravel's Route Model Binding. What you can do is go into your model and create a function like this:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'postcode';
}
```

Yet, I see an issue with that that can cause you some issues down the road. What happens when you have multiple companies with the same postcode?  How will Laravel know which one you want?
A much better option is going to be to use the id field and retrieve your company with it. Unless you make the postalcode field in the database a unique field. Which again raises the question of what happens when you have two or more companies wanting access to your website that share the same postal code?

Comment: "What happens when you have multiple companies with the same postcode? " No, I'm not select company from postcode, that code is to populate other field from postcode. I'm using route in company because I'm not make other controller again. if you see, the problem is in the url of ajax, I test the url using localhost in browser and that can return data, in ajax if I using localhost url that return data too.